# Ceiling fan make thumping noise at the beginning

Tags: ceiling-fan, smart-switch

I just install a single pole Kasa smart switch (HS200), intended to use to turn on/off my ceiling fan. However, when I turn on the fan, it'd rocking back and forth and make loud thumping noise (like someone from the upstair stomp their feet) for like 2 seconds, then everything works fine. I also notice this slightly happens when I use the fan control to change the speed.

Does anyone know why does this happen? Is it possible that the switch is not compatible?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Imagine the fan is mounted loosely or has become loose. Can also be bad bearings in the fan.  When fan starts up or changes speed, it forces movement.

Comment: Like crip659, I suspect this has nothing whatsoever to do with the switch and that it's the ceiling fan mount itself that's loose. You may want to check to ensure that the box the fan is mounted to is A) a ceiling fan rated box, B) that it's mounted securely, and C) if there's a mounting bracket (not directly mounted to a ceiling joist) that the bracket is rated for a ceiling fan and is installed properly

Comment: There is a possibility of it falling with the blades still spinning.  Not a fun place to be.

Comment: It could be that the blade is also out of balance, if so it will vibrate while running.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies! I take a look at the fan but not sure how to fix the mounting. Here's a video demonstrating the sounds: https://youtube.com/shorts/QlCVv5VoO2M

And some few other pics: https://imgur.com/a/WxqAY42

It looks pretty scary!

Comment: The video seems to be more of a bad bearing/something binding in the fan itself.  The motor has a problem to start the fan spinning, it takes a bit of force to start spinning.  How or if it is repairable is unknown.

Comment: Is it a safety hazard to let the fan runs in this case?

Comment: Bad bearings can get red hot(have scorched a few hay bales).  They are also probably holding the fan in place(depends on design).  Would say it is a hazard to keep using, it only gets worst.

Comment: Ah shoot, get i'll have to call an electrician to see what's up. Thanks a lot for the answer!!!!

Comment: It's worth making sure that your smart switch doesn't do a "fade in". Some smart switches slowly increase the current in order to make your lights look like they're fading in, but for a ceiling fan this will underpower the motor. If your motor is underpowered it won't get up to speed, which allows it to balance properly.